# aligning a website across multiple computers

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, alignment

Ok, so i have 2 pages of code that work perfectly and that I'm completely happy with. The only problem is that when i go on another computer to see how the website looks the alignment with all the elements in the coding is off. I created the website on a macbook pro and when i access it on my iMac, nothing is in the same spot as it was on the macbook pro. How do i make a website look the same on any computer that i use? Is there a certain way to code this in css? I have tried to make the positions, but then i just makes a big mess.

Comment: Look into responsive design. There isn't really a quick fix, but rather learning a different way to design your websites from the start.

Comment: Try resizing the browser window on the one with the biggest screen (the iMac) and seeing how your web page changes. If you make the window really big do you see what you expect? What about if you make the window really small? Try this on other sites and see how they react.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried implementing Bootstrap? Depending on the project, I try to use 'col-sm-xx' to start off; to make it scalable for mobile/small devices.